# Sleep mode active and disable in Android

Tags: android, sleep-mode

I want to sleep to device in android and after 5 minutes active device,disable sleep mode,When I try below code,it works and get sleep mode with uses below code

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT,miliseconds);
```

When I try disable sleep mode and actice device,it doesn't active device how can I active and disable sleep mode in android?

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,miliseconds);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sleep mode"?

Comment: Sleping device like above, i tried that used screen of timeout but when i use it,after i can’t awake(turn screen on) device